# How to parse [email protected] data with JSOUP

Tags: email, parsing, jsoup

Is there a way to parse an email address by JSOUP which is protected by this piece of code:

```
<a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="29484e4a404a4c50404469484e4a404a4c504044074a4644">[email&#160;protected]</a>
```

While parsing with standard `elements.select(".email").text();` it returns `[email protected]`. 
I tried to google this but found a lot of unrelated info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The email address is "encrypted" by XORing every character in the email address with some randomly generated first byte. Decode the hex string into a byte array and XOR all of the bytes with the first one to decrypt the address.

For example (in Python):

```
In [1]: cfemail = '29484e4a404a4c50404469484e4a404a4c504044074a4644'

In [2]: encoded_bytes = bytes.fromhex(cfemail)

In [3]: encoded_bytes
Out[3]: b')HNJ@JLP@DiHNJ@JLP@D\x07JFD'

In [4]: bytes(byte ^ encoded_bytes[0] for byte in encoded_bytes[1:])
Out[4]: b'agciceyim@agciceyim.com'
```

Comment: To get encrypted email use `elements.select(".email").attr("data-cfemail")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have implemented it in and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same login in Java:

```
public static String convertToEmail(String hex) {

    try {
        byte[] decoded = Hex.decodeHex(hex);
        byte firstByte = decoded[0];

        byte[] newBytes = new byte[decoded.length - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
            byte result = (byte) (decoded[i] ^ firstByte);

            if (i == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            newBytes[i - 1] = result;
        }

        return new String(newBytes);

    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

`Hex` is imported from here `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` in

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String decrypt(String encryptedEmail) {
    int xorKey = Integer.parseInt(encryptedEmail, 0, 2, 16);
    final StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 2; i < encryptedEmail.length(); i += 2) {
        int charCode = Integer.parseInt(encryptedEmail, i, i + 2, 16) ^ xorKey;
        email.append((char) charCode);
    }
    return email.toString();
}
```

Java method to decode CloudFlare hex string without using any library